# Error including bouncycastle provider

Tags: java, gradle, bouncycastle

I need to use `bouncycastle provider` library in my project.

I have included it the gradle project.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
version = '1.0.0'
mainClassName = 'path.to.main.file'

    dependencies {
        compile "org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:+"
        compile "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:+"
        compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:+"
        testCompile "junit:junit:+"
    }
```

The project build successfully. But when I try to run the project. It is not able to find the `bouncycastle`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
    at com.example.Server.main(Server.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Wrong dependency. There is no bcprov-jdk16. It should be bcprov-jdk15on

Comment: @JamesKPolk you are wrong, there is. Up until version 1.46, so there is something found. In recent versions not though, as I wrote below already.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't run your application correctly.
If you just run the created JAR with `java -jar foo.jar`, you miss all dependencies at runtime.
You have to add those dependencies to your classpath.

You have various ways to do this.
E. g. you can create a fat JAR where all dependencies are repacked into the final JAR with some Gradle plugin (there are several, but I don't like this solution at all, so I cannot recomment one).
Or you can e. g. apply the `application` plugin, then you can use the `run` task to correctly run your application and use the `distZip` task to get a ready-made distribution ZIP with your app, all dependencies and start scripts that correctly set the runtime classpath.
Or you can e. g. manually do it with `java -cp foo.jar;other.jar;another.jar your.main.Class`.

Comment: I have edited the question.  Still I get the same error. I made the plugin to `application` and specified the path to the main file.

Comment: But you still do `java -jar foo.jar`, don't you? This is not what I told you and what the documentation of the `application` plugin tells you.

Comment: I am using the `run` task in `Android Studio` to run the application.

Comment: A Run configuration that you manually built where the libraries are missing because you didn't sync the Module definition with the Gradle file changes and thust he depencies are missing, or the Gradle `run` task out of the Gradle tool window?

Comment: I am running from the `gradle` run task under application in the 'Gradle Projects` window.

Comment: Btw. I don't think it is your actual problem, but as you should change it anyway, you can try if it changes anything. `bcprov-jdk16` is most probably not correct. Only up to 1.46 there were dedicated `jdk16` artifacts. In newer versions there are only the `jdk15on` artifacts that you should use if you have at least Java 5.

Comment: @Vampire: Yes, he simply has the wrong artifact. Also, for old versions of android you need to use the spongycastle provider because the bouncycastle provider will have namespace conflicts with standard android java runtime.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Nothing suggests he is using Android besides using Android Studio. But as it is just a specialized IntelliJ IDEA he can develop any program with it and neither tags nor the build script contain any hint pointing to Android, but to plain Java application. The latest `bcprov-jdk16` version 1.46 also has the class Java is complaining about, that's why I think that this might **not** fix his problem, even if probably not what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and got resolved by checking whether the `BouncyCastleProvider` class is loaded into JVM or not. IF not then only load the `BouncyCastleProvider` class.

Scenarios where some other applications deployed on the Server has already loaded the `BouncyCastleProvider` class. When you are deploying the other war file and loading the same class this leads to the following exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
```

Problem Occured while exceuting the following code:

```java
static {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

Solution:

```java
static {
    addBCProvider();
    //Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
}
public static void addBCProvider() {
    // java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BC
    if (Security.getProvider(org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null) {
        System.out.println("JVM Installing BouncyCastle Security Providers to the Runtime");
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    } else {
        System.out.println("JVM Installed with BouncyCastle Security Providers");
    }
}
```